# header is executed directly

Tags: php

I am using a if condition and in that there is some script and then header.
But the script wont work and directly header works.

```
if(strpos(mysql_error(),'Email')!=false)
{
print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'alert("The email address is already registered")'; 
print '</script>';  
header('Location: register.php');
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't be using PHP `mysql` functions anymore, considering they've been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Comment: didnt code php in quite a while, but dont recognize the `!==` operator. So maybe use `!=` instead. Plus, this is a VERY bad way to check if the mail address was already registered... you should handle this by yourself and not let the `UNIQUE` database constraint throw and error and catch it that way

Comment: @Najzero the `!==` (also exists in javascript) is a typed equality operator that doesn't auto-cast.

Comment: You are doing something really wrong. I reckon you just insert the email address and check on the error if the key already exists? Better is to retrieve the email from the database, and if you get results, it already exists.

Answer (score 3):

**Replace header with typical JS**. That does the trick.

```
if(strpos(mysql_error(),'Email')!==false)
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('The email address is already registered')
window.location.href='register.php';
</SCRIPT>");
}
```

Comment: upvoted, as it is most likely the thing the questionare wanted

Comment: 16:19:34 you, and me: 16:18:23

Comment: @Akam, Take it cool, well both answers are different. You've used a lot of print statements whilst i used a single echo.

Comment: the same problem exists.The page redirects without showing alert box

Comment: @NitishBangad, No way mate. It's very well tested. Can you try pasting exactly the same script and try ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different things wrong in your code.

First, the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) calls should be the **first thing** you *output*. You don't do that. You have unbuffered `print`s before it. From the (very good) PHP documentation:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Second, even if you would have used buffered output, the Javascript would never execute as the body is not evaluated when there is a `Location` header.

Third, using `mysql_error` to find out if a certain record exists isn't the way to go. Better would be something along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
SELECT email FROM table WHERE email="someEmail"
if (rows found) {
   alert "email already exists"
}
```

Finally, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Good luck learning webdevelopment!

Comment: Moreover, any output before or after `header('Location: ...')` is unnecessary because user will be redirected and content will not be shown.

Comment: @Imieee wrong. Output **before** header will break the header call. The user is only redirected if the browser supports the `Location` header. Extra info can be possible, for example in API calls.

Comment: The point here is: JavaScript will not be executed, because once browser receives the header it redirect

Comment: @Akam the point is, that his `header` call **will not work**.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs I agree with the first sentence, but in this case there is also no need to output anything. I don't know any modern browser that does not support the `Location` header. :)

Comment: @Imieee all browser might support it, but nowadays a lot of HTTP connections are used for APIs, where the designer might use the `Location` header and also output some info.

Comment: While I agree that it's frustrating seeing people making such elementary mistakes, there are factual errors in the answer provided here and it does not address acheiving the result the OP wants.

Comment: @symcbean could you point out the factual errors, so I can correct them? Note that I updated the answer to address other issues. Also, other people have given different solutions. I think my answer should give the poster enough ideas and pointers on how to a) fix his problem and b) become a better programmer. In cases like this, I don't believe in just giving the solution to his problem, but give a solution path.

Comment: You can use header() after print/echo as long as output is bufferred. Also redirecting via the HTTP headers prevents the body of the response being parsed - hence even if output was buffered in the code, the javascript would not execute.

Comment: @symcbean agreed. I updated my answer. Also removed the frustration sneers (should have done that in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
window.location = "example.html";
```

See @Bart Friederichs's answer first, even if header works perfectly, the JavaScript alert wont work Because the page will be redirected once its completed and the browser will not execute the JavaScript for you.

```
<?php
print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'alert("The email address is already registered");'; 
print 'window.location = "register";';
print '</script>';  
?>
```

You could also output it without PHP! for example:

```
if(strpos(mysql_error(),'Email')!==false)
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("The email address is already registered");
window.location = "register.php";
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```